# printing the winning individual from a genetic algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic

I am looking through this code I have found, and I cant work out how to print the winning individual.
Essentially, I'm trying to produce a genetic algorithm that will produce an individual of N numbers that sums to a total X.
This question was went through on Lethian: http://lethain.com/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/  But I cant seem to work out how to print the individual which is the result of the evolution.

Heres some example code:

```
    from random import randint, random
    from operator import add
    target = 5 #this defines the target number we are trying to reach
    p_count = 100 #this defines the number of individuals available to                                        mutate for the desired result
    i_length = 6 #this defines the length of each individual, the number of intergers in it
    i_min = 0 #this defines the minimum value of an integer in the individual
    i_max = 100 #this defines the maximum value of an integer in the individual
    def individual(length, min, max):
        return [ randint(min,max) for x in xrange(length) ] #Creates an individual. Defines an individual by the number of numbers contained in it and their min/max
    def population(count, length, min, max):
        return [ individual(length, min, max) for x in xrange(count) ] #Creates population from individuals. This sets the number of individuals in the    population (count), the number of numbers in each individual (length), and the min and max numbers for the individual        
    def fitness(individual, target):
        sum = reduce(add, individual, 0)
        return abs(target-sum) #determines the fitness. does this by adding the indivduals numbers together, and taking that value from the target value 
    def grade(pop, target):
        summed = reduce(add, (fitness(x, target) for x in pop))
        return summed / (len(pop) * 1.0) #This returns an average fitness to compare populations to.
    def evolve(pop, target, retain=0.2, random_select=0.05, mutate=0.01): #This evolves a population, retaining 20%, randomly selecting 5% so it doesnt get stuck/lose variance, and mutates 1%.
        graded = [ (fitness(x, target), x) for x in pop]
        graded = [ x[1] for x in sorted(graded)]
        retain_length = int(len(graded)*retain)
        parents = graded[:retain_length]
        for individual in graded[retain_length:]:
            if random_select > random():
                parents.append(individual)
        for individual in parents:
            if mutate > random():
                pos_to_mutate = randint(0, len(individual)-1)
                individual[pos_to_mutate] = randint(
                    min(individual), max(individual))
        parents_length = len(parents)
        desired_length = len(pop) - parents_length
        children = []
        while len(children) < desired_length:
            male = randint(0, parents_length-1)
            female = randint(0, parents_length-1)
            if male != female:
                male = parents[male]
                female = parents[female]
                half = int(len(male) / 2)
                child = male[:half] + female[half:]
                children.append(child)
        parents.extend(children)
        return parents
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The algorithm evolve doesn't give you an individual, it gives you a population

Comment: Your code snippet only contains helper functions, the algorithm is missing... You would start off with a population (by calling `population`) and then evolving that multiple times (by calling `evolve`). At some point you would probably pick the best individual in the population.

Comment: It looks like you will have to repeatedly call `evolve()` followed by a check to see whether any individual in the population reached the target

Answer (score -1):

if i understood u correctly u are want to print a candidate solution that matches ur criteria (like higher than particular fitness)
if so
you can:

```
   def fitness(individual, target):
    sum = reduce(add, individual, 0)
    if sum >= target:
      print individual
    return abs(target-sum)
```